# Make PHPWord template-generated document auto-downloaded instead of saved locally

Tags: php, codeigniter, browser, download, phpword

[PHPWord](http://phpword.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro.html) has an excellent template example but I checked its code and it saves the file locally (taken from `../Examples/Template.php`):

```
$document = $PHPWord->loadTemplate('Template.docx');
...
$document->save('Solarsystem.docx');
```

Compared to one who uses the `createWriter` method which has an option to auto-download:

```
$objWriter = PHPWord_IOFactory::createWriter($PHPWord, 'Word2007');
$objWriter->save('php://output');
```

Is auto-download possible for templates? (see `PHPWord/Template.php::save`)

I do not want it to be saved locally to remove the task of creating a garbage collection when an auto-download option available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used PHPWord's sample `Sample_23_TemplateBlock.php` to test this solution and it worked:

```
// Add HTTP headers to force user's browser save document
// instead of opening it like an HTML page
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=template.docx");

// $templateProcessor->saveAs('results/Sample_23_TemplateBlock.docx');
$templateProcessor->saveAs('php://output');
```